# Duplicate Event in Parent Window

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I have an iframe on my page.  The iframe has the same origin as my page, so I shouldn't need to worry too much about cross-origin security problems.

On the parent frame, I have a `keydown` event listener watching for certain key presses.  But if the iframe has the focus, the `keydown` events are registered in the iframe only.

**I would like to duplicate the iframe `keydown` event on the parent frame.**

Is this possible?  I have been looking at `document.createEvent` and `evt.initEvent` but I am not there yet.  Also, if I create a `keydown` event, will this actually act like the user typed a character?  I.e., can I direct them to a field on the parent document?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery, declare a wrapper function in your parent that trigger keydown of your input element:

```
function triggerKeyDown(){
    $("#my_input").keydown();
}
```

In your iframe, call

```
window.parent.triggerKeyDown();
```

to trigger the keydown event in your parent window.